# AJAX requests from native mobile applications

Tags: ios, ajax, sencha-touch-2, native

I have been researching on this subject and am still a bit confused.

I have a Sencha Touch 2 which is working perfectly on my machine. This is for the simple reason that I have a configured proxy on my machine's apache which allows me to call the server without the need of an absolute path. i.e. the requests are made from my machine to the server in the following manner:

```
url: /folder/subfolder/etc
```

The app also works if accessed publicly on the domain abc.mydomain.com since the server is on the same browser and obviously it works.

What I need to know is the following:

I am now going to deploy this app as a native IOS application. The URLs won't work if they are left absolute since the phone will not resolve that path due to the fact that there is no proxy configured. However, would they work if I change them to absolute URLs? From what I have read, mobile phones do not consider the access-origin problem therefore it should work.

Hence, if I have the following request:

```
var L_AssetAjaxConnection = new Ext.data.Connection();
        L_AssetAjaxConnection.request({
            url: /folder/subfolder/etc
            timeout: 60000,

            success: function(P_Response){
               console.write('success');
            }
        });

            failure: function(P_Response){
               console.write('failed');
            }
```

and before I deploy on IOS I change it to:

```
var L_AssetAjaxConnection = new Ext.data.Connection();
        L_AssetAjaxConnection.request({
            url: http://mydomain.com/folder/subfolder/etc
            timeout: 60000,

            success: function(P_Response){
               console.write('success');
            }

            failure: function(P_Response){
               console.write('failed');
            }
        });
```

This won't work on the desktop. However, should it work upon deploying on the iPhone?

Looking forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it out on my Android phone and as it turns out, yes, absolute URLs work on native apps but won't work on desktop pcs due to security issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your domain, in which case things will work in any app, native or not. Both techniques are supported by Sencha (see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/ajax) and [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP))

Comment: I know but jsonp encapsulates the url in a javascript <script> and appends it to the ajax call path which wouldn't work for me.